# ios 10 when app is in foreground no notification alert is show even with UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

In ios 10+, in the AppDelegate.h file, I import UserNotifications and set the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate like below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
```

Then in the AppDelegate.m file, I add `[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];` inside my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Then I add the userNotificationCenterhandler as below.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter* )center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification* )notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);

  }
```

but when the app is in foreground no alert is show :( what did i miss ?

Answer (score 0):

**Apple says:** *If you receive local or remote notifications while your app is running in the foreground, you’re responsible for passing the information to your users in an app-specific way.*
when app is in foreground `notification delegate` is called. You need to implement alert in

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: delegate
```

Comment: It makes sense: since if the app is in the foreground, it's right in front of the user, therefore there's no need to present a notification to the notification center. I've seen a number of developers attempt to claim it's a "bug" when it is new behaviour in iOS10+, and they have trouble understanding the change

Comment: no, not anymore in ios 10 you can now decide to show the alert to the end user when the app is in foreground (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1143773/iOS-User-Notification-features: ios10 : Notification gets displayed even if App is in foreground ) - read Get notification when App is in foreground section

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of when using the older notifications - they won't appear